# Enable and run sipservlets on openliberty

Tags: open-liberty

I am looking at using openliberty as you seem to support the sipservlet module.

Looking at your docs it is only described in the reference section which doesn't provide any examples of use.

Assuming that it follows the standard I tried to run a simple example.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.sip.*;

public class SimpleSIPServlet extends SipServlet {
    protected void doMessage(SipServletRequest req)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        SipServletResponse res = req.createResponse(200);
        res.send();
    }
}
```

However the basic import javax.servlet.sip.*; fails as unresolvable.

Added it as a feature to server.xml but still ignores it so followed the final instruction to add it to a feature manifest file but it doesn't say how to do this or where to put it.
Tried adding it to target/liberty/wlp/lib/features/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.servlet-3.1.mf but again with little success.

The reference doesn't mention adding anything to the pom so not sure how this gets pulled in.

How do I enable this feature and are there any examples of usage?

Here is a trace log of the issue

```
*******************************************************************************
product = Open Liberty 21.0.0.4 (wlp-1.0.51.cl210420210407-0944)
wlp.install.dir = /home/sysadmin/src-ccmnext/guide-getting-started/start/target/liberty/wlp/
java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
java.version = 11.0.10
java.runtime = OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
os = Linux (4.15.0-136-generic; amd64) (en_US)
process = 27080@u18dev
trace.specification = *=info:com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.*=all
********************************************************************************
[4/27/21, 16:24:04:986 UTC] 0000001c id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.TraceSpecification               I TRAS0018I: The trace state has been changed. The new trace state is *=info:com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.*=all.
[4/27/21, 16:24:05:577 UTC] 00000001 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           I CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 3.845 seconds
[4/27/21, 16:24:05:665 UTC] 00000020 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0007I: Feature update started.
[4/27/21, 16:24:08:010 UTC] 00000016 id=00000000 .apache.cxf.cxf.core.3.2:1.0.51.cl210420210407-0944(id=185)] I Aries Blueprint packages not available. So namespaces will not be registered
[4/27/21, 16:24:08:363 UTC] 00000014 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.security.ready.internal.SecurityReadyServiceImpl  I CWWKS0007I: The security service is starting...
[4/27/21, 16:24:08:874 UTC] 00000015 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.monitor.DropinMonitor        A CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications.
[4/27/21, 16:24:09:827 UTC] 00000018 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.cache.ServerCache                                 I DYNA1001I: WebSphere Dynamic Cache instance named baseCache initialized successfully.
[4/27/21, 16:24:09:832 UTC] 00000018 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.cache.ServerCache                                 I DYNA1071I: The cache provider default is being used.
[4/27/21, 16:24:09:834 UTC] 00000018 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheServiceImpl                            I DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully.
[4/27/21, 16:24:12:073 UTC] 00000014 id=00000000 ibm.ws.security.authentication.internal.jaas.JAASServiceImpl I CWWKS1123I: The collective authentication plugin with class name NullCollectiveAuthenticationPlugin has been activated. 
[4/27/21, 16:24:12:132 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.security.token.ltpa.internal.LTPAKeyCreateTask    I CWWKS4105I: LTPA configuration is ready after 0.170 seconds.
[4/27/21, 16:24:14:339 UTC] 0000001c id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.WSKeyStore                             A CWPKI0820A: The default keystore has been created using the 'keystore_password' environment variable.
[4/27/21, 16:24:14:764 UTC] 0000001c id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.WSKeyStore                             I Successfully loaded default keystore: /home/sysadmin/src-ccmnext/guide-getting-started/start/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/resources/security/key.p12 of type: PKCS12
[4/27/21, 16:24:14:965 UTC] 00000014 id=00000000 SessionMgrComponentImpl                                      I initialize SESN8501I: The session manager did not find a persistent storage location; HttpSession objects will be stored in the local application server's memory.
[4/27/21, 16:24:15:322 UTC] 00000014 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O SipContainerMBean activated
[4/27/21, 16:24:15:335 UTC] 00000014 id=00000000 om.ibm.ws.microprofile.metrics.monitor.MonitorMetricsHandler I CWPMI2003I: Monitoring metrics can be retrieved through mpMetrics.
[4/27/21, 16:24:16:419 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      I CWWKZ0018I: Starting application guide-getting-started.
[4/27/21, 16:24:16:424 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 bm.ws.app.manager.war.internal.WARDeployedAppInfoFactoryImpl I CWWKZ0134I: The guide-getting-started application is using the loose application definition at the /home/sysadmin/src-ccmnext/guide-getting-started/start/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/guide-getting-started.war.xml location.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:072 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: PublicMicroProfileMetrics.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:066 UTC] 00000027 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: health.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:073 UTC] 00000021 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: ibm/api.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:074 UTC] 00000027 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost              I addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module health has been bound to default_host.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:076 UTC] 00000021 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost              I addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module ibm/api has been bound to default_host.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:074 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost              I addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module PublicMicroProfileMetrics has been bound to default_host.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:085 UTC] 00000027 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://u18dev:9080/health/
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:089 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://u18dev:9080/metrics/
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:096 UTC] 00000021 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://u18dev:9080/ibm/api/
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:166 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.stack.transaction.SIPTransactionStack         I CWSCT0321I: SIP stack init configuration
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:299 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.stack.transaction.SIPTransactionStack         I CWSCT0322I: SIP stack init transport.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:302 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.stack.transaction.SIPTransactionStack         I CWSCT0323I: SIP stack init finished.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:359 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 SessionContextRegistryImpl                                   I getSessionContext SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/metrics
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:359 UTC] 00000026 id=00000000 SessionContextRegistryImpl                                   I getSessionContext SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/ibm/api
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:357 UTC] 00000023 id=00000000 SessionContextRegistryImpl                                   I getSessionContext SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/health
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:426 UTC] 00000021 id=00000000 m.ibm.ws.sip.stack.transaction.transport.SIPConnectionsModel I CWSCT0328I: SIP starting to listen on sip:u18dev:5060;udp.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:427 UTC] 00000021 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.protocol.SipProtocolLayer           I CWSCT0028I: SIP Container Listening Point u18dev:5,060/udp
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:522 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.SipContainer                        I CWSCT0001I: SIP Container initialization completed.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:523 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 IDGeneratorImpl                                              I IDGeneratorImpl SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:523 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.SipContainer                        I CWSCT0002I: SIP Container Version: 8.0
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:527 UTC] 00000021 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.udpchannel.internal.UDPChannel                    I CWWKO0400I: UDP Channel UDP_InboundUDPChain_defaultSipEndpoint is listening on host *  (IPv4) port 5060.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:545 UTC] 00000023 id=00000000 IDGeneratorImpl                                              I IDGeneratorImpl SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:554 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 setDescription  description = 
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:557 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 Setting main siplet: SimpleSIPServlet for applciation: SemafoneSSRGateway old name: null
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:562 UTC] 00000021 id=00000000 m.ibm.ws.sip.stack.transaction.transport.SIPConnectionsModel I CWSCT0328I: SIP starting to listen on sip:u18dev:5060;tcp.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:562 UTC] 00000021 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.protocol.SipProtocolLayer           I CWSCT0028I: SIP Container Listening Point u18dev:5,060/tcp
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:567 UTC] 00000026 id=00000000 IDGeneratorImpl                                              I IDGeneratorImpl SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:589 UTC] 00000021 id=00000000 m.ibm.ws.sip.stack.transaction.transport.SIPConnectionsModel I CWSCT0328I: SIP starting to listen on sips:u18dev:5061;tls.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:590 UTC] 00000021 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.protocol.SipProtocolLayer           I CWSCT0028I: SIP Container Listening Point u18dev:5,061/tls
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:601 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 Setting main siplet: SimpleSIPServlet for applciation: SemafoneSSRGateway old name: SimpleSIPServlet
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:601 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 addSipServlets  addSipServlet - getRootURI = null
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:602 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 isJSR289Application: m_app_name = SemafoneSSRGateway  =  true
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:827 UTC] 00000023 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheServiceImpl                            I DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:945 UTC] 00000023 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper               I init SRVE0242I: [com.ibm.ws.microprofile.health.2.0] [/health] [HealthCheckReadinessServlet]: Initialization successful.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:953 UTC] 00000023 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper               I init SRVE0242I: [com.ibm.ws.microprofile.health.2.0] [/health] [HealthCheckServlet]: Initialization successful.
[4/27/21, 16:24:17:955 UTC] 00000023 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper               I init SRVE0242I: [com.ibm.ws.microprofile.health.2.0] [/health] [HealthCheckLivenessServlet]: Initialization successful.
[4/27/21, 16:24:18:003 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup                         I <clinit> WELD-000900: 3.1.4 (Final)
[4/27/21, 16:24:18:159 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper               I init SRVE0242I: [com.ibm.ws.microprofile.metrics.public] [/metrics] [PublicMetricsRESTProxyServlet]: Initialization successful.
[4/27/21, 16:24:18:202 UTC] 00000027 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.mbeans.PluginGenerator          I SRVE9103I: A configuration file for a web server plugin was automatically generated for this server at /home/sysadmin/src-ccmnext/guide-getting-started/start/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/logs/state/plugin-cfg.xml.
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:723 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 setWebApp   setWebApp = com.ibm.ws.webcontainer40.osgi.webapp.WebApp40@2cd3b769[guide-getting-started#guide-getting-started.war]
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:725 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: Liberty Project.
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:725 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost              I addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module Liberty Project has been bound to default_host.
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:726 UTC] 00000024 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://u18dev:9080/
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:731 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 SessionContextRegistryImpl                                   I getSessionContext SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:732 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 IDGeneratorImpl                                              I IDGeneratorImpl SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:755 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 setIsDuringWebAppInitialization  isDuringWebAppInitialization = true
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:755 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 setWasInitialized  wasInitialized = true
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:856 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.ServletsInstanceHolder       3 ServletsInstanceHolder  ServletsInstanceHolder constructor
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:860 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.appqueue.MessageDispatcher          I CWSCT0433I: SIP Container queues stats print mode= 0 . 1 = only when overloaded, 2 = always. once every 1,000 msec.
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:897 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 setRootURI  /
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:897 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   > setIsDistributed Entry  
                                                                                                               false
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:899 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   > setApplicationKeyMethod, @SipApplicationKey not defined Entry 
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:920 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.mbeans.PluginGenerator          I SRVE9103I: A configuration file for a web server plugin was automatically generated for this server at /home/sysadmin/src-ccmnext/guide-getting-started/start/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/logs/state/plugin-cfg.xml.
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:926 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0001I: Application guide-getting-started started in 3.507 seconds.
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:984 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.servlets.SipSessionsUtilImpl        E Error retrieving application descriptor for application name: Liberty Project
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:989 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O Init SIP Servlet!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:995 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O SIP Factory set.
[4/27/21, 16:24:19:996 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O init. OutboundInterfaceList:
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:004 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O     OutboundInterface:sip:u18dev:5060;transport=udp
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:006 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O     OutboundInterface:sip:u18dev:5060;transport=tcp
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:008 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O     OutboundInterface:sip:u18dev:5060;transport=tcp
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:009 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.ServletsInstanceHolder       3 addSipletInstance  appName[Liberty Project] class[io.openliberty.sample.system.SimpleSIPServlet] instance[io.openliberty.sample.system.SimpleSIPServlet@64fd8a6a]
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:009 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.ServletsInstanceHolder       3 addSipletInstance  found sipAppDesc [null]
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:059 UTC] 00000020 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPPort                       I CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host *  (IPv6) port 9080.
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:064 UTC] 00000020 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPPort                       I CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint-ssl has been started and is now listening for requests on host *  (IPv6) port 9443.
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:065 UTC] 00000020 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPPort                       I CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel TCP_InboundTCPChain_defaultSipEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host *  (IPv6) port 5060.
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:066 UTC] 00000020 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPPort                       I CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel TCP-ssl_InboundTLSChain_defaultSipEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host *  (IPv6) port 5061.
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:089 UTC] 00000020 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [cdi-2.0, distributedMap-1.0, jaxrs-2.1, jaxrsClient-2.1, jndi-1.0, json-1.0, jsonp-1.1, monitor-1.0, mpConfig-1.4, mpHealth-2.2, mpMetrics-2.3, servlet-4.0, sipServlet-1.1, ssl-1.0].
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:090 UTC] 00000020 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 14.511 seconds.
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:090 UTC] 00000020 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0011I: The defaultServer server is ready to run a smarter planet. The defaultServer server started in 18.363 seconds.
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:223 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.NullPointerException com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init 181" at ffdc_21.04.27_16.24.20.0.log
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:230 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper               E init SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [SimpleSIPServlet] in application [guide-getting-started]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.ServletsInstanceHolder.addSipletInstance(ServletsInstanceHolder.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.sip.container.servlets.SipServletUtilImpl.initSiplet(SipServletUtilImpl.java:32)
    at javax.servlet.sip.SipServlet.init(SipServlet.java:752)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:298)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1400)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:1201)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:1169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1067)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6687)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:470)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:1179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.access$100(WebContainer.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer$3.run(WebContainer.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:238)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

[4/27/21, 16:24:20:290 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp                        E doLoadOnStartupActions SRVE0276E: Error while initializing Servlet [SimpleSIPServlet]: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:367)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1400)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:1201)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:1169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1067)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6687)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:470)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:1179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.access$100(WebContainer.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer$3.run(WebContainer.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:238)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.ServletsInstanceHolder.addSipletInstance(ServletsInstanceHolder.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.sip.container.servlets.SipServletUtilImpl.initSiplet(SipServletUtilImpl.java:32)
    at javax.servlet.sip.SipServlet.init(SipServlet.java:752)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:298)
    ... 16 more

[4/27/21, 16:24:20:300 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   > setVirtualHost Entry  
                                                                                                               default_host
                                                                                                               [*:9443, *:-1, *:9080]
[4/27/21, 16:24:20:301 UTC] 00000025 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   < setVirtualHost = Port = 9080 _Host = * Exit 
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:412 UTC] 00000021 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.dar.ApplicationRepositoryFactory              I CWSCT0405I: The application router is configured to select applications by its start.
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:417 UTC] 00000021 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.dar.ApplicationRepositoryFactory              I CWSCT0424I: Loading default application router, start order strategy.
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:418 UTC] 00000021 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.dar.DefaultApplicationRouter                  I CWSCT0401I: Default application router has been initialized.
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:443 UTC] 00000021 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 isJSR289Application: m_app_name = SemafoneSSRGateway  =  true
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:487 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 isJSR289Application: m_app_name = SemafoneSSRGateway  =  true
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:608 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O Init SIP Servlet!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:609 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O SIP Factory set.
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:610 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O init. OutboundInterfaceList:
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:610 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O     OutboundInterface:sip:u18dev:5060;transport=udp
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:612 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O     OutboundInterface:sip:u18dev:5060;transport=tcp
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:612 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O     OutboundInterface:sip:u18dev:5060;transport=tcp
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:613 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.ServletsInstanceHolder       3 addSipletInstance  appName[Liberty Project] class[io.openliberty.sample.system.SimpleSIPServlet] instance[io.openliberty.sample.system.SimpleSIPServlet@64fd8a6a]
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:613 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.ServletsInstanceHolder       3 addSipletInstance  found sipAppDesc [null]
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:613 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.ServletsInstanceHolder       E addSipletInstance: can not add listeners
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:614 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.ServletsInstanceHolder       3 triggerSipletInitServlet  found sipAppDesc [null]
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:614 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper               I init SRVE0242I: [guide-getting-started] [/] [SimpleSIPServlet]: Initialization successful.
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:615 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 isJSR289Application: m_app_name = SemafoneSSRGateway  =  true
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:615 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 isJSR289Application: m_app_name = SemafoneSSRGateway  =  true
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:616 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O OPTIONS Request from null
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:617 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 SystemOut                                                    O OPTION PING received!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:624 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 isJSR289Application: m_app_name = SemafoneSSRGateway  =  true
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:624 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 isJSR289Application: m_app_name = SemafoneSSRGateway  =  true
[4/27/21, 16:24:24:642 UTC] 00000022 id=00000000 com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.SipAppDesc                   3 isJSR289Application: m_app_name = SemafoneSSRGateway  =  true
```

Comment: From the [doc](https://openliberty.io/docs/21.0.0.3/reference/feature/sipServlet-1.1.html) you can enable with the ``<feature>sipServlet-1.1</feature>``.   Not sure what examples exist though.

Answer (score 1):

#### pom.xml compile dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.openliberty.features</groupId>
            <artifactId>sipServlet-1.1</artifactId>
            <type>esa</type>
            <version>21.0.0.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

#### server.xml feature config

```
<server description="Sample Liberty server">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>sipServlet-1.1</feature>
    </featureManager>
```

Feature config doc [reference](https://openliberty.io/docs/21.0.0.3/reference/feature/sipServlet-1.1.html)

#### Notes

You can typically declare a dependency to any feature providing an API using this **esa**-type dependency construct (the version is the Open Liberty runtime version number).   Many of our features though are part of the Jakarta / MicroProfile platform APIs and so are easier to bring in through the aggregate APIs of those platforms.

#### Further reading

SIP in WebSphere Liberty (guessing it's pretty similar to the story in Open Liberty):
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=overview-session-initiation-protocol-sip

#### Older doc

Finally, not going to vouch for these but you might get some context too from these links:

1. SIP in [WebSphere traditional](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=applications-sip-servlets) - Not sure how much of this is relevant in Open Liberty but I'm guessing some?
2. A SIP-related [sample](https://github.com/WASdev/sample.rtcomm.sip.gateway).  The Maven constructs and use of the liberty-maven-plugin are old and not recommended.  It's better to use patterns in the newer [Open Liberty Guides](https://openliberty.io/guides/)  samples.  Still, perhaps there's something to be learned here?

Comment: Many thanks for the reply I will work my way through those docs and see how I do.

Comment: Just to confirm however, do I need the last section to enable this? 
> Developing a feature that depends on this feature
If you are developing a feature that depends on this feature, include the following item in the Subsystem-Content header in your feature manifest file.

com.ibm.websphere.appserver.sipServlet-1.1; type="osgi.subsystem.feature"

Is this needed and where do I put it?

I put it in target/liberty/wlp/lib/features/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.servlet-3.1.mf.
Is this correct?

Comment: Are you developing your own user feature, to configure in server.xml?   If not you can ignore doc phrased like:   "If you are developing a feature that depends on this feature".  If you're not sure then you're probably not developing a user feature.  I'm not familiar enough with SIP to guess how likely it'd be that you'd want your own user feature though.

Comment: Sort of getting there, the documentation is a bit sparse on specifics and examples.
One problem I have found is that the annotations don't work as expected.
A common construction is 
@SipServlet
public class MyServlet extends SipServlet {
 ...
}
But when you try to apply this the SipServlet annotation clashes with the SipServlet extension and it won't allow both to be defined with the same name?

Comment: You can use the fully-qualified class name on an annotation, like:  `@javax.servlet.sip.annotation.SipServlet(...) public class MyServlet extends SipServlet`.

Comment: I think I am missing something in the underlying configuration.
The server now responds but always with a SIP 500 error.
In the log it says...
"Error retirieving application descriptor for application name: Liberty Project"  "SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [SimpleSIPServlet] in application [guide-getting-started]: java.lang.NullPointerException"
SimpleSIPServlet is the class I'm using which it enters but it always fails at init(). I assume there is something that init() needs that I am not supplying through the config?

Comment: As an update I have now sort of got it working but the first time the servlet is used you get the above error. All subsequent requests work fine?

Comment: Hmm..I'm noticing there's a loadonStartup attr in the annotation in the sample at https://github.com/WASdev/sample.rtcomm.sip.gateway/blob/master/rtcomm-sip-gateway-application/src/main/java/net/wasdev/rtcommsipgateway/servlets/WebRTCGatewayServlet.java#L50:  `@javax.servlet.sip.annotation.SipServlet(description = "The main servlet for the gateway application", name = "WebRTCGatewayServlet", loadOnStartup=1)`    Could that be related?

Comment: Thanks, using load on startup just triggers the exception at startup rather than on the first use. It does then ensure all subsequent messages work but you still get the exception. I assume I am not priming the service in some way to pre-empt this as the exception never seems to enter the inti function but does on the next attempt?
The following makes the init work (eventually)...     
@Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);

Comment: Is it possibly the config that is null and needs to be initialised before use?

Comment: Update: the config entry is not needed as just the super.init() seems to be the main requirement so there is still something else that needs to be set prior to calling. Could it be the annotations as I am not using a sip.xml even though it says the annotations mean you don't need it? What should the @SipApplication(name="") be set to?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that an NPE is thrown in your servlet. Try to change the content of the `init` method as follows and see if the exception is still thrown. Look for an `in init` message in the `messages.log` file. If you are still getting the same error, provide the content of your war file.

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("in init");
}
```

Comment: This does not work at all and permanently throws the NPE whenever tested.
You need...
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config); 
But as indicated above, even with this the first attempt at starting the servlet fails without even entering the overridden init. Perhaps the config is not valid at that point so how do I set the config initially?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the same NPE as before? It seems that the NPE is thrown in the `init` method. Try to replace the content of the `init` method with

```
System.out.println("UAS has been initialized");
```

Redeploy your application and restart the server. Are you still getting the same error? Do you see a `UAS has been initialized` message in `messages.log`?

Comment: With LoadonStartup=1 you get immediately: 
[INFO] [AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The defaultServer server is ready to run a smarter planet. The defaultServer server started in 8.808 seconds.
[INFO] [ERROR   ] Error retirieving application descriptor for application name: Liberty Project
[INFO] Init SIP Servlet!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
[INFO] SIP Factory set.

Comment: Followed by: 
[INFO] [ERROR   ] SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [SimpleSIPServlet] in application [guide-getting-started]: java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO]  at com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.ServletsInstanceHolder.addSipletInstance(ServletsInstanceHolder.java:100)
[INFO]  at [internal classes]

Comment: Subsequent first message fires the INIT() again and processes the message without NPE and then all subsequent message work as normal.

Comment: Just seems to be the first time the init is run something is missing but is then provided for subsequent calls.

Comment: can you please enable traces as follows?
`<logging traceSpecification="com.ibm.ws.sip.container.parser.*=all/>`. Then restart the server and provide a snippet from `trace.log` (including the NPE stack trace).

Comment: See trace log in main question body

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for this NPE is a missing attribute in the `@SipServlet` annotation.
Can you verify please if you have the `description` property set?
For example:

```
@javax.servlet.sip.annotation.SipServlet(
        description = "My servlet", 
        name = MySipServlet", loadOnStartup=1)
```

If no, please add the missing attribute, redeploy the application, restart the server and see if the issue is still reproducible.

Comment: The above trace was run whilst this was setup as you have indicated and made no difference.

Comment: can you share the war file please? I can try to install it locally and see what's missing.

Comment: How would you like to share it?

Comment: If you are an IBM customer, you can open a case and upload all the details / files there.

Comment: I am an open source user so not an option.

Comment: Given that in the IBM world it seems these background setting are configured automatically could it be something missing in the server.xml? What settings should there be in that file to support sip servlets. Is there an example?

Comment: I believe you should be able to open a `GitHub` issue then and attach the files.

Comment: Opened an issue on openliberty/docs/Enable and run sipservlets on openliberty #4152

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I must add package-info.java to package dir where is sip servlet implemented

`package-info.java`

```java
@SipApplication(
        name = "name",
        mainServlet = "SipNameServlet",
        description = "description",
        displayName = "display name"
)
package pl.xxx.yyy.sip;

import javax.servlet.sip.annotation.SipApplication;
```